# Erlang Mysql Source Command

Tags: mysql, erlang

I am using erlang odbc module to connect to mysql and it is working fine for almost all my commands like *insert,delete,create,use,drop* . But here i need to use the *source* command to load a file which contain all the commands like create and use database and create some 10 tables... but when i use it like `odbc:sql_query(Database_Connection,"source filename")` i am getting error and getting disconnected. The file is present in the current directory, i tried giving both the absolute and relative path to the file. PLease do suggest how to use the source command in erlang odbc.

Answer (score 2):

there is no such 'source' sql command in mysql.

There is 'source' command in the mysql shell utlility. But it's just a command for mysql shell (to read and send sql commands to server).

Comment: +1 very true. He ought to read this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_mysql_Command-Line_Tool

Answer (score 1):

'source' is MySQL CLI command rather than SQL one. I haven't used erlang ODBC personally, but I had similar problem when using JDBC. As far as I remember there was no other option but reading the SQL script, splitting it into separate statements and running them separately one by one.